# pandas groupby expanding df based on unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have `df` below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
    'V1': [False, False, True, True, False, True],
    'V2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C']
})
```

I want to achieve the following. For each unique `ID`, the bottom row is `True` (this is `V1`). I want to count how many times each unique value of `V2` occurs where `V1==True`. This part would be achieved by something like:

```
df.groupby('V2').V1.sum()
```

However, I also want to add, for each unique value of `V2`, a column indicating how many times that value occurred after the point where `V1==True` for the `V2` value indicated by the row. I understand this might sound confusing; here's how the output woud look like in this example:

```
df
    V2  V1  A   B   C
0   A   0   0   0   0
1   B   1   0   0   0
2   C   2   1   2   0
```

It is important that the solution is general enough to be applicable on a similar case with more unique values than just `A`, `B` and `C`.

**UPDATE**

As a bonus, I am also interested in how, instead of the count, one can instead return the sum of some value column, under the same conditions, divided by the corresponding `"count"` in the rows. Example: suppose we now depart from `df` below instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
    'V1': [False, False, True, True, False, True],
    'V2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'V3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
})
```

The output would need to sum `V3` for the cases indicated by the counts in the solution by @jezrael, and divide that number by `V1`. The output would instead look like:

```
df
    V2  V1  A   B   C
0   A   0   0   0   0
1   B   1   0   0   0
2   C   2   1   3.5 0
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why in row 2 in your output the columns A and B have value 1 and 2.

Comment: That is because there are two cases where `(V2==C) & (V1==True)`. Once where `ID==c` and once where `ID==a`. In the first group (`c`) there is only one subsequent case where `V2==B`. In the second group (`a`) there are two subsequent rows, one where `V2==B` and another where `V==A`. Therefore, in the final row, column `A` equals `1` and column `B` equals `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('V2').V1.sum().astype(int).reset_index()
print (df1)
  V2  V1
0  A   0
1  B   1
2  C   2
```

Then grouping by `ID` and create heper column by last value by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `last`, then remove last rows of `ID` by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for counts, add all possible unique values of `V2` and last append to `df1` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
val = df['V2'].unique()
df['new'] = df.groupby('ID').V2.transform('last')
df = df[df.duplicated('ID', keep='last')]

df = pd.crosstab(df['new'], df['V2']).reindex(columns=val, index=val, fill_value=0)

df = df1.join(df, on='V2')
print (df)
  V2  V1  A  B  C
0  A   0  0  0  0
1  B   1  0  0  0
2  C   2  1  2  0
```

**UPDATE**

The updated part of the question should be possible to achieve by changing the [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) part with [`pivot table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(
    index='n',
    columns='V2',
    aggfunc=({
        'V3': 'mean'
    })
).V3.reindex(columns=v, index=v, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close; how do I get `V1` in there as well? (+ get rid of the `new` name - basically like the example output).

Comment: @CHRD - Give me  asec,

Comment: Added an update to the question and tried to answer it (edited your original answer).